# Is this search algorithm request appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I want to ask a question to find an algorithm.  This specific question feels like a UX question to me, but I can also see the counter argument to that.  Is this the correct site to ask for a search algorithm to best meet the needs of my users?

Here is the question I want to ask:

> I have hundreds of items for the user to search through.  I am trying
> to find the best search algorithm.  I am currently using the
> [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm, but it does not suit my needs for
> the following reason.
>
> Things user can search for: "Pool", "Pool Table", "Table"
>
> When the user types in "Pool", I want the results to come back with
> both "Pool" and "Pool Table".  But with the Levenshtein Distance
> algorithm, I can only return "Pool".
>
> One solution is for me to run the algorithm on each word, and find my
> results like that.  But I don't know if there is a better way, and I
> do not want to reinvent the wheel.
>
> What is the best search algorithm for a user to search a database of
> strings that meets my above criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not suited to the site. Because you've already solved the User Experience part of the problem:

> When the user types in "Pool", I want the results to come back with both "Pool" and "Pool Table".

What you're not looking for is implementation advice on how to create this user experience.

Answer (score 1):

There are many similar questions on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), so I believe that is a good place to post it.